# ElementTree : extract attribute value using findall and append value to list

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

Wanted to extract the value of name attribute from inter tag and also append the group name with the name tag if group value is present. I tried to extract using  xml.etree.ElementTree but my code is not giving expected output.

**Input XML**

```
<abtshop>
    <dDirectory>dub</dDirectory>
    <S>statusd</S>
    <work>worklogs</work>
    <custs>
        <cust>nim-us</cust>
    </custs>

    <mileage>999</mileage>

    <defaults>
        <default type="mercley">
            <user>dairy</user>
            <exec>slm.sh</exec>
            <env>
                <var name="SAN_HOME">youyou-11</var>
            </env>
        </default>
    </defaults>
    <inters>
        <inter name="nim_turk" first-day="20230301" historical="20220103" market="multi">
            <works>
                <work kind="obopay" run="jbs">
                    <args>
                        <arg name="distance">180000</arg>
                    </args>
                </work>
                <work kind="silkb" run="jbs">
                    <args>
                        <arg name="distance">180000</arg>
                    </args>
                </work>
            </works>
        </inter>
        <inter name="nim_us_m" first-day="20230301" historical="20220103" market="lone">
            <works>
                <work kind="obopay" run="jbs" groups="groupA,groupB">
                    <args>
                        <arg name="distance">120000</arg>
                        <arg name="jbsopt">xmas_size=1200000</arg>
                        <arg name="jbsopt">of_obopaying_threads=2</arg>
                    </args>
                </work>
                <work kind="silkb" run="jbs" groups="groupA,groupB">
                    <args>
                        <arg name="distance">120000</arg>
                        <arg name="jbsopt">xmas_size=1200000</arg>
                    </args>
                </work>
            </works>
        </inter>
    </inters>
</abtshop>
```

**Required Logic**

If work tag has attribute groups then need value with name and group appended else print only the name.

```
  <inter name="nim_us_m" first-day="20230301" historical="20220103" market="lone">
    <works>
        <work kind="obopay" run="jbs" groups="groupA,groupB">
```

like

```
nim_us_m-groupA, nim_us_m-groupB
```

else, print only the name

```
<inter name="nim_turk" first-day="20230301" historical="20220103" market="multi">
```

like this

```
nim_turk
```

I have tried below code, to extract the value but vain.

**Tried Code**

```
tree=ET.parse('test.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
xm_subs=[]
for subn in root.findall(".//inter/works/work[@run='jbs'][@kind='obopay']/../.."):
        sname=subn.attrib["name"]
        for subg in root.findall(".//inter[@name='%s']/jobs/job[@run='jbs'][@kind='obopay'][@groups]" % sname):
                        groups=subg.attrib['groups']
                        for gname in groups.split(","):
                                sub_name=subn.attrib["name"] + "-" + gname
                                xm_subs.append(sub_name)

        else:
                xm_subs.append(subn.attrib["name"])
print xm_subs
```

**Required Output**

```
['nim_turk','nim_us_m-groupA','nim_us_m-groupB']
```

Comment: please explain the logic of building the required output.

Comment: Your xml insn't valid. in line 52 there is a closing tag, which never opened?  Your searched content like "nim_turk-groupB" is not conteained into the shared XML! Which python version do you use? Python3 print use brakets like print().

Comment: @Hermann12 I have update the  xml and required output now.

Comment: @Hermann12 - I have verified with https://codebeautify.org/xmlvalidator, it is showing valid xml, not sure what is going wrong

Comment: @iamsage now it's correct and well-formed xml. Only the question from Mr. balderman is still open?

Comment: @Hermann12 wanted to get the value of name attrib from inter tag as it is if there is no group, if it has groups present then wanted to add the group values appended with name with hyphen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should show you the required list:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

root = ET.parse("test_xml.xml").getroot()

result =[]
user = ''
for elem in root.findall('.//inters'):
    for name in elem:
        user = name.get('name')
        gr = name.find(".//work[@groups]")
        if gr is not None:
            l = gr.get('groups').split(',')
            for u_gr in l:
                comb_usr = user + '_' + u_gr
                result.append(comb_usr)
        else:
            result.append(user)

print(result)
```